# API for Google Collections (not Java collections but www.google.com/save)

Tags: google-api, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-api-js-client

When you are viewing a recipe on Google Nest Hub it allows you to say "Save this recipe" and the recipe is saved to Google Collections (https://www.google.com/save). At a later date you can then say "show my cookbook" and it will display a list of recipes that you have previously saved. (You can also find your favourite locations and images at Google Collections.

...Is there an API to query and add items to collections? I suspect there is not, because the page uses an XHR request:

```
https://www.google.com/_/SaveUi/data/batchexecute?
    rpcids=...&f.sid=...
    &bl=boq_saveuiserver_20200107.03_p0
    &hl=en-GB&soc-app=...&soc-platform=1&soc-device=1&_reqid=...&rt=c
```

Comment: I have the exact same question!